# Perl get request returns empty response, maybe session related?

Tags: perl, session, cookies, get

I was using an open source tool called SimTT which gets an URL of a tabletennis league and then calculates the probable results (e.g. ranking of teams and players). Unfortunately the webpage moved to a different webpage.

I downloaded the open source and repaired the parsing of the webpage, but currently I'm only able to download the page manually and read it then from a file.

Below you can find an excerpt of my code to retrieve the page. It prints success, but the response is empty. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with perl and webtechniques very well, but in Wireshark I could see that one of the last things send was a new session key. But I'm not sure, if the problem is related to cookies, ssl or something like that.

It would be very nice if someone could help me to get access. I know that there are some people out there which would like to use the tool.

So heres the code:

```
use LWP::UserAgent ();
use HTTP::Cookies;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(keep_alive=>1);
$ua->agent('Mozilla/5.0');
$ua->cookie_jar({});
my $request = new HTTP::Request('GET', 'https://www.mytischtennis.de/clicktt/ByTTV/18-19/ligen/Bezirksoberliga/gruppe/323819/mannschaftsmeldungen/vr');
my $response = $ua->request($request);

if ($response->is_success) {
    print "Success: ", $response->decoded_content;
}
else {
    die $response->status_line;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either there is some rudimentary anti-bot protection at the server or the server is misconfigured or otherwise broken. It looks like it  expects to have an `Accept-Encoding` header in the request which LWP by default does not sent. The value of this header does not really seem to matter, i.e. the server will send the content compressed with `gzip` if the client claims to support it but it will send uncompressed data if the client offered only a compression method which is unknown to the server.

With this knowledge one can change the code like this:

```
my $request = HTTP::Request->new('GET',
    'https://www.mytischtennis.de/clicktt/ByTTV/18-19/ligen/Bezirksoberliga/gruppe/323819/mannschaftsmeldungen/vr',
    [ 'Accept-Encoding' => 'foobar' ]
);
```

With this simple change the code works currently for me. Note that it might change at any time if the server setup will be changed, i.e. it might then need other workarounds.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was searching for hours for this solution! How did you find out, that this was the problem?

Comment: *"How did you find out, that this was the problem?"* - experience with several similar issues: I've taken the original working request from the browser, fed it directly via socket (i.e. w/o LWP) to the server and then reduced the request as much as possible to find out what the relevant part is the server is looking for. Then I've added this part to the HTTP::Request.

Comment: *Note that it might change at any time if the server setup will be changed, i.e. it might then need other workarounds.* Which is why the best approach here would be to ask the owners of the web site to supply an API giving access to their data.